# Confusion about the use of "key=" in sorted() function

Tags: python-3.x

```
ls = [-12, 23, -35, 3, 43, -234]

print(sorted(ls, key=abs))  # ---way1
print(sorted(ls, key=lambda key: abs(key)))  # ---way2
```

I want to sort the elements in ls by absolute value，and when I express it like way1 ,I get a warning "Unexpected type(s): (List[int], (__x: SupportsAbs[_T]) -> _T) Possible type(s): (Iterable[int], (int) -> SupportsLessThan) (Iterable[int], None) ", but when I express it like way2, it is ok.
What is the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug in your IDE's static analysis (pycharm?). FWIW, `mypy` gives no errors for the above code.

Comment: Yup. Works just fine for me

Comment: Yes, the IDE which I used is pycharm